# Summation/multiplication of a list of tuples

Tags: scala

I'm trying to figure out a simple operation that takes a list of `(Int, Int)` tuples and multiplies the tuples internally and then sums those results. Example:

```
val list = ((9, 4), (1, 5), (4, 6))
```

Would evaluate to `(36, 5, 24)`, which would then evaluate to 65. I was thinking I could take the list then pattern match for a single tuple, not unlike:

```
list.map{
   case x => x(0)._1 * x(0)._2
}
```

But this would just take the first tuple and multiply each component. I suppose I could do an aggregation, but I don't know how I'd approach that.

Comment: Traverse the collection only once: `list.foldLeft(0){case (s,(a,b)) => s + a*b}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

((9, 4), (1, 5), (4, 6)) is not a list but rather a tuple of tuples

```
val list = List[(Int, Int)]((9, 4), (1, 5), (4, 6))
val result = list.map{ case (a, b) => a * b }.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

First take all tuples and multiply the components. This can be done by using a `map` which will process each tuple individually. After that call `sum` on the resulting list which will sum all elements together.

```
val res = list.map(x => x._1 * x._2).sum
```

The `case` is not necessary here and you can't use `(0)` since the elements of the list is tuples, not lists themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListBuffer` way as

```
val list = ((9, 4), (1, 5), (4, 6))
val listBuffer = new ListBuffer[Int]
for(tuple <- list.productIterator){
  val (a, b) = tuple.asInstanceOf[Tuple2[Int, Int]]
  listBuffer += a * b
}
```

which should give you

```
ListBuffer(36, 5, 24)
```

and calling `sum` function as `listBuffer.sum` should give you `65`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `collect` on a `list`

```
scala> val list = List((9, 4), (1, 5), (4, 6))
list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((9,4), (1,5), (4,6))

scala> list.collect{
  case ele => ele._1 * ele._2
}.sum
res1: Int = 65
```